# Using Phantom JS to convert all HTML files in a folder to PNG

Tags: windows, png, phantomjs

I've started using Phantom JS on Windows, but I'm having a bit of difficulty finding documentation on its capability (probably the root of my problem).

Using Phantom JS I would like to do the following:

1. Give it a local machine folder location,
2. Have it navigate to that location and identify the list of HTML files,
3. Once that list is identified to loop of the the list of HTML files and convert them all to PNG (similar to the way the rasterize.js example works), where the filename gsubs "HTML" with "PNG".

I'm sure this is probably possible, but I wasn't able to find the Phantom JS function call for:

1. getting the list of files in a folder and
2. the format for gsub and grep in Phantom JS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var page = require('webpage').create(), loadInProgress = false, fs = require('fs');
var htmlFiles = new Array();
console.log(fs.workingDirectory);
var curdir = fs.list(fs.workingDirectory);

// loop through files and folders
for(var i = 0; i< curdir.length; i++)
{
    var fullpath = fs.workingDirectory + fs.separator + curdir[i];
    // check if item is a file
    if(fs.isFile(fullpath))
    {
        // check that file is html
        if(fullpath.indexOf('.html') != -1)
        {
            // show full path of file
            console.log('File path: ' + fullpath);
            htmlFiles.push(fullpath);
        }
    }
}

console.log('Number of Html Files: ' + htmlFiles.length);

// output pages as PNG
var pageindex = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!loadInProgress && pageindex < htmlFiles.length) {
        console.log("image " + (pageindex + 1));
        page.open(htmlFiles[pageindex]);
    }
    if (pageindex == htmlFiles.length) {
        console.log("image render complete!");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}, 250);

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log('page ' + (pageindex + 1) + ' load started');
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    page.render("images/output" + (pageindex + 1) + ".png");
    console.log('page ' + (pageindex + 1) + ' load finished');
    pageindex++;
}
```

Hope this helps. For more information about the FileSystem calls, check this page out: http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/

Also, I wanted to add, that I believe the FileSystem functions are only available in PhantomJS 1.3 or later. Please make sure to run the [latest](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) version. I used PyPhantomJS for Windows but I'm sure this will work without a hitch on other systems as well.

Comment: Somehow I only get blank `PNG`s with your script. Adding `console.log(page.content);` in `page.onLoadFinished` returns `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` no matter want the real HTML content is… Any suggestions? Phantomjs v1.9.2

Comment: Are you sure that your pages are loading fully before you're attempting to take snapshots?

Comment: I checked for `status` as well. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939046/phantomjs-fails-to-open-local-file