# PhantomJS fails to open local file

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to open a local HTML-file with PhantomJS (version 1.9.2):

```
var page = require('webpage').create(), fs = require('fs'),
    address = "/Full/Path/To/test.html";

console.log('isFile? ' + fs.isFile(address));
console.log('isReadable? ' + fs.isReadable(address));
page.open(address, function(status){
    console.log('status? ' + status);
    console.log(page.content)
    phantom.exit();
});
```

First I check if I got the right path and if the file is readable using `fs.isFile()` & `fs.isReadable()`. Then I check whether phantomjs succeeded in opening the file (with `status`). Independent of the actual contents of the file I always get:

```
isFile? true
isReadable? true
status? fail
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

So the file and the path seem to be okay – but PhantomJS fails to open it!
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you use the page.onLoadFinished callback like I have in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7549515/541404

Comment: Also, what operating system are you using? You may want to use `fs.separator` to get the appropriate file system separator. For example, if you're in Windows, your separator will be "\", but if you're in a Unix\OS X variant, you'll use "/".

Comment: I was missing the third "/" on "file:///". It made phantom give me success as status but <html><head></head><body></body></html> as content. Weird.

Answer (score 53):

PhantomJS can open local files without any problems. The url have to follow classic Url/Uri rules, especially for a [local file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

`/Full/Path/To/test.html` is not valid for PhantomJS. Is it a local file or a web resource?

Depending of the path, just try with something like this:

```
file:///C:/Full/Path/To/test.html
```

or if it's hosted in a web server:

```
http://localhost/Full/Path/To/test.html
```

Comment: @MiguelAlejandroFuentesLopez: Unix path is not a full Uniform Resource Identifier as described in [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986).

Answer (score 4):

An addition to @Cybermaxs answer: If you need to convert a simple relative path `test.html` to a proper URL, you can do so by something like this:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

function getFileUrl(str) {
  var pathName = fs.absolute(str).replace(/\\/g, '/');
  // Windows drive letter must be prefixed with a slash
  if (pathName[0] !== "/") {
    pathName = "/" + pathName;
  }
  return encodeURI("file://" + pathName);
};

var fileUrl = getFileUrl("test.html");
```

Note that you can't use a [solution based on `file-url`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214523/1804173) because it is based on `path` and `process`, which do not work within PhantomJS. Fortunately, the [`fs`](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/absolute.html) module provides similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As of phantom 2.1.1 (possibly earlier) the method described by OP actually works as written.