# phantomjs - render HTML to PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I have problems with rendering a HTML file to a PDF file. I pass two arguments to the command line. The first is the HTML input file and the second the PDF output

```
/var/bin/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /var/www/nodejs/html_to_pdf.js /root/input.html /root/hello.pdf
```

## code

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    args = require('system').args,
    f = require('fs').open(args[1], 'r');

page.paperSize = {
    format : 'A4',
    orientation : 'portrait',
    margin : {
        top : '1cm',
        left : '1cm',
        bottom : '1cm',
        right : '1cm'
    }
};

page.content = f.read();
page.setContent(page.content, page);
page.render(args[2]);
phantom.exit();
```

No errors is returned and no output PDF file?

Here is the input file

http://www.filedropper.com/input_3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest rewrite to `page.open` a file:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var args = require('system').args;
var fs = require('fs');

function getFileUrl(str) {
  var pathName = fs.absolute(str).replace(/\\/g, '/');
  // Windows drive letter must be prefixed with a slash
  if (pathName[0] !== "/") {
    pathName = "/" + pathName;
  }
  return encodeURI("file://" + pathName);
};

page.paperSize = {
    format : 'A4',
    orientation : 'portrait',
    margin : {
        top : '1cm',
        left : '1cm',
        bottom : '1cm',
        right : '1cm'
    }
};

page.open(getFileUrl(args[1]), function(){
    page.render(args[2]);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

[image]

`getFileUrl` is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43951047/2715393)