# Command Line Search Through Folder - Multiple Options

Tags: command-line

How can I use the command line to search through a folder of html and css files identifying **html** files that:

- Have divs with class .highlight
- Have img tags
- Do **not** have divs with class .main

Comment: Analogous to [this answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7549515/1470607), you can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to open the files and then check if they fulfill all the requirements you have. You can then, for example, return a list of the files that do fulfill your requirements. PhantomJS (headless Webkit) has the advantage that it won't simply die on ill-formed XML (as opposed to some parsers).

Answer (score 1):

For simple queries you can use grep (avaliable on *nix platforms usually, can install on Windows as well) which uses regular expressions, but that would only work in one case here.  For your image tags:

```
    grep -R <img *.html
```

Otherwise you would actually need a parser because what you are talking about requires parsing html tags and examining their contents.  There are many libraries out there for this- but it's not something built into the command line.

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)